# FreeBSD - how to create linked list(s) in the kernel?

Tags: freebsd, kernel

I'm doing a project right now and the project is to manipulate linked list(s) in the kernel. The project will implement a "toy" locking mechanism, in which all the locks are in a linked list(s). Please help me out in the following questions:

1) How to create a linked list in the kernel? Can I use functions in ? Or simply malloc(),etc.?

2) Locks are grouped by "lock group name" in this project, does this mean there should be multiple linked lists and each linked list represent a "lock group"? Thank you!

Comment: in question 1) i mean "functions in sys/queue.h"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **queue(3)** man page documents some very useful macros in sys/queue.h, implementing lists and tail queues. This header also available in kernel.

Memory allocation in kernel documented in **malloc(9)** man page. Generally it's just like user-level malloc, but with additional *type* parameter useful for finding memory leaks. Your code should look like this:

```
MALLOC_DEFINE(M_MYMALLOC, "mydata", "Some data");
struct foo {
    SLIST_ENTRY(foo) chain;
};
struct foo *bar = malloc(1000, M_MYMALLOC, M_WAITOK);
SLIST_INSERT_HEAD(&head, bar, chain);
SLIST_REMOVE_HEAD(&head, chain);
free(var, M_MYMALLOC);
```

2) It's hard to answer this question without knowing what "grouping" mean in context of your project.

Comment: 1) should I use SLIST_HEAD(foohead, foo) head; struct foohead *headp first? How to keep this linked list in memory? (i.e. if I wrote a system call that creates this linked list, the next time I call this system call, it doesn't create the linked list again because the linked list is already in memory.) 2) I'm writing a system call, should I include the definition of the struct in the code of the system call itself, or in a header?

Comment: also, do I need MALLOC_DECLARE(M_MYMALLOC) before I can MALLOC_DEFINE()?